# Receiving touchmove events when scrolling a child iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, mobile

I'm developing a mobile-designed webapp which loads content into an internal iframe. This frame updates its height every time new content is loaded to avoid scrolling inside the iframe. In that way I have a long iframe which is scrolled in the context of the main webapp. This is currently working well in Safari and Chrome for iOS. The most simple example of the app structure is:

```
<div id="header">
    <p>Scroll: <span id="scroll"></span></p>
    <p>Touchmove: <span id="touchmove"></span></p>
</div>
<iframe src="https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html" class="frame-style" id="uframe"></iframe>
```

In order to trigger certain visual effects I need to know the current Y-axis position of the application's content. I'm using Jquery's bind function to receive *touchmove* events from touch devices. *Scroll* events are not very useful since on mobile devices they are only triggered at the end of the scrolling, I need to know the position of the Y-axis every time it has been changed by scrolling. Unfortunately I discovered *touchmove* events aren't triggered when scrolling starts touching the iframe's contents. I'm using these statements:

```
$(window).bind('touchmove', 
           function(){        
   console.log('touchmove='+window.pageYOffset); //Show in console
   $('#touchmove').html(window.pageYOffset); //Update value in document
});
```

So the question is: **Is there any way to receive *touchmove* events when scrolling a child iframe?**

The running example can be checked on: http://jsfiddle.net/badger_cl/b9322/1/
To try it on a mobile device you can access: http://fiddle.jshell.net/badger_cl/b9322/1/show/light/

The red stripe is a div element, when the touch-scrolling starts from this element, it updates the *touchmove* value. When the scrolling starts at the iframe content (The Android dashboard in this case), it doesn't update the *touchmove* value. *Scroll* updates are shown just to demonstrate it only updates at the end of the scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to `touchmove` event both on parent page and on page loaded into the iframe.

Next you will need to communicate from iframe to parent window that `touchmove` event happened. You can use `Window.postMessage` method for this.

Send message from iframe:

`window.parent.postMessage(messageObj);`

Receive message in parent window:

`window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
  var messageObj = event.data;
});`

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage