# Can't drag in an HTML5 in an iFrame on a mobile phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an HTML5 game in an Iframe such as follows.

```
<div>
    <iframe href="path-to-html5-game"/>
</div>
```

I have a draggable range slider in the HTML5 game.

If I open the page on an Android phone, all the buttons work, but the slider doesn't move on being dragged, and instead the iframe gets highlighted blue.

I believed that the interaction with the iframe is the interference.

I have tried: -

1)

```
iframe.addEventListener("click, touchstart, touchend, touchmove", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

2. 

```
<iframe unselectable = "on" onselectstart="return false;" />
```

3. 

```
<iframe style="
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select:none;
    user-select: none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;" />
```

4. 

In the HTML5 file

```
<style>
body{
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    touch-action: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
</style>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('ontouchstart', function(e) {e.preventDefault()}, false);
    document.addEventListener('ontouchmove', function(e) {e.preventDefault()}, false);
</script>
```

I have tried all of the solutions on both the container div and on the iframe, to no avail.

Comment: Note: `.addEventListener` only takes one event type. You can't use `"click, touchstart, touchend, touchmove"`. You'd have to declare four event handlers separately. They can all use the same function, but they still need to be declared individually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receiving touchmove events when scrolling a child iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514714/receiving-touchmove-events-when-scrolling-a-child-iframe)